# How to add a layer, from ArcGIS Online, to Web AppBuilder at run-time

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

This is similar to my previous question [How to add a layer to Web AppBuilder at run-time](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188838/how-to-add-a-layer-to-web-appbuilder-at-run-time)

But in this case I want to access layers from ArcGIS Online, similar to the way that the *> Add > Search For Layers* function works from the default ArcGIS Online map viewer:

[image]

This brings up a window listing layers stored in my ArcGIS Online account, and allows them to be added to the map.

Is a similar function available in Web AppBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but a workaround: you can switch AGOL maps run-time by adding `itemid={mapId}` into the querystring + reload. If you have more AGOL maps with different sets of layers, you can in fact add/remove AGOL layers at runtime.